# how to parse json data from url using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I need to parse json data from the url

http://www.apilayer.net/api/live?access_key=f40041...&format=1

and i need the value for `"USDAED"` and assign it to input.

```
{
  "success":true,
  "terms":"https:\/\/currencylayer.com\/terms",
  "privacy":"https:\/\/currencylayer.com\/privacy",
  "timestamp":1483594992,
  "source":"USD",
  "quotes":{
    "USDAED":3.672802,
    "USDAFN":66.699997,
    "USDALL":129.729996,
    "USDAMD":483.440002,
    "USDANG":1.76987,
    "USDAOA":165.078003,
    "USDARS":16.059999,
  }
}
```

Comment: You can use `$.getJSON()`, What's the issue?

Comment: paste the complete url ..Question not clear.

Comment: @Satpal, you mean like this http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VPYbYN

Comment: this question has been answered several thousand times already. could you post what you tried/which resources didn't work for you?

Comment: @atulquest93 I've removed the access key because it has a limited access quote

Comment: @Learning http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qREmdQ?editors=1011#0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$.getJSON()` to get data, the `.val()` to input value;

```js
var URL = "http://www.example.com/...................."
$.getJSON(URL, function(d) {
  console.log(d.quotes.USDAED)
  $('#dummy').val(d.quotes.USDAED)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id='dummy'/>
```